# Can't check nested object variables in a single line

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to show a welcome-modal to user on his first time to that page.

This code works fine:

```
if(this.app_data) {
  if(this.app_data['company']){
    if(this.app_data['company']['welcomed'] === false){
      this.openWelcomeModal();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the messy code checking nested variable structure.

The clear way to do it would be use a single line like this:

```
if(this.app_data['company']['welcomed'] === false){
  this.openWelcomeModal();
}
```

But this generates error:

> ```
>     core.js:7376 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'welcomed')
>         at SafeSubscriber._next (game.page.ts:46:39)
> ```

Is there any way to do it in a single line, without need to check each level of nested object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to the rescue!

```
if(this.app_data?.['company']?.['welcomed'] === false){
  this.openWelcomeModal();
}
```

Comment: this generates compile error on dots `error TS1109: Expression expected.`... i'm only able to use this syntax without error on template parsing.

Comment: The syntax above is valid, check this TypeScript playground: https://tsplay.dev/mAd1RN. You may have another syntax issue in your code?

Comment: @anderlaini Please [edit] your question to show a [mre] that displays the error you are encountering.